# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception while trying to call a webservice from my android Services?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-asynctask, android-jetpack, android-async-http

I have a scenario where I need to call the Webservices from the Android Services.
Currently I am starting the Services from the Activity by

```
Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, AServices.class);
            if (!isMyServiceRunning(AServices.class)) {
                startService(mServiceIntent);
            }
```

But I am getting an exception as android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. As I am following MVVM Architecture so is there any way or alternative that I can call it from AsyncTask and any other stuffs?

Comment: There is no webservice call in your code. There is no code that can cause that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Service runs on the UI Thread. If you need a Service extend `IntentService` or the newly `JobIntentService` and not `Service`. Both `IntentService` (`onHandleIntent`) and `JobIntentService` (`onHandleWork`) will be executed on thread != from the UI/Main thread